# Updating user attributes for multiple models being created in same form Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bit of a weird situation (at least I think it's weird..)

When I create a new account in my app I also create the account owner (devise user)

Where I'm running into the problem is I need to add the account_id to the owner record and add the owner_id to the account record. the owner can then invite users to their account, and those users will need to have the account_id set on their record. As it stands right now when i try to create the account and the owner, I get the following server output and error: (Note the account dose not exist, nor dose the user -- its a clean database.. I am 100% certain this is failing due to how my relationships are set up.

```
(byebug) @account.valid?
  Account Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE LOWER("accounts"."subdomain") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "taurengroup"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
false
(byebug) @account.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007faf15f91660 @base=#<Account id: nil, subdomain: "taurengroup", owner_id: nil, plan_id: nil, phone_verified: false, email_verified: false, account_active: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"owner.account"=>["must exist"]}, @details={:"owner.account"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

my `Account` model

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS = %w(www admin loadlead)

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :users

  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :subdomain, presence: true,
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            format: { with: /\A[\w\-]+\Z/i, message: 'Contains invalid characters' },
            exclusion: { in: RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS, message: 'restricted name'}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner

  before_validation :downcase_subdomain

private

  def downcase_subdomain
    self.subdomain = subdomain.try(:downcase)
  end

end
```

my `User` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:system_admin, :owner, :admin, :user]
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  validates :f_name, :l_name, :country_code, :phone_number, presence: true

  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  belongs_to :account
private

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

end
```

my `AccountController` create method:

```
  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    byebug
    if @account.valid?
      @account.owner.update_attributes(role: 1) 
      @account.owner.update_attributes(account_id: @account.id)
      @aaccount.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Company subdomain created successfully.'
    else
      render action: 'new', alert: 'There was a problem. Please try again.'
    end
  end
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

My server output when attempting to create:

```
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-09 21:21:05 -0600
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pH8vf0MtXpZ/rtyFw8dJ1XKeJ3heR9Mk8deDWWGDgbxrtgrtSuNvpmB2iVIs178z8g1AcSBrumm7DJCwqnoWEg==", "account"=>{"owner_attributes"=>{"f_name"=>"xxxxxx", "m_name"=>"xxxxxx", "l_name"=>"xxxxxx", "country_code"=>"1", "phone_number"=>"xxxxxxxx", "email"=>"xxxxxx@taurenltd.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "subdomain"=>"TaurenGroup"}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
```

Comment: Seems like the association is not set properly

Comment: both side you are using belongs to in `user` and `account`

Comment: That’s what I said in the question.. not sure how to fix it

Comment: Do you have `account_id` in user model

Comment: No just account_id

Comment: because the owner is just a class of user

Comment: Then I think you should change it to 
`account belongs_to owner` and `user has_one account`

Comment: 1) You are checking the record if it is valid before assigning owner's `role` and `account_id` in the controller. Of course it is invalid at that moment! It validates not only `account`, but also `account.owner`;  2) Do not use `update_attributes` method here. The params should be assigned like this `@account.owner.role = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got this all hooked up.. its working.. maybe there is a better way???

`User` model

```
belongs_to :account
```

`Account` model

```
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :users
```

doing this has allowed me to not have to update or create attributes for the associations on create.

Thanks for all your input!